# how to resolve influxdb.conf parse config error

Tags: docker, influxdb

while running influxdb:1.0 in docker i get this following error

> [run] 2019/01/13 09:04:14 InfluxDB starting, version 1.0.2, branch master, commit ff307047057b7797418998a4ed709b0c0f346324
>
> [run] 2019/01/13 09:04:14 Go version go1.6.2, GOMAXPROCS set to 1
>
> [run] 2019/01/13 09:04:14 Using configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
>   run: parse config: Near line 1 (last key parsed 'Merging'): Expected key separator '=', but got 'w' instead.

this is my first 3 lines from .conf file

> Merging with configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
>   reporting-disabled = false
>   bind-address = ":8088"

does anybody know how to resolve this?
thanks

Comment: can you add influxdb.conf to the question?

Comment: i dont understand why you give -1 ?

Comment: I didn't, i just asked for the configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the configuration file that you posted you have the following issue at the first line:

```
Merging with configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

Is being treated as a normal config line so it should be in a form like this

```
Merging = with configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

What you need to do is to comment the first line to avoid this issue.

The second note on your config file - it is not related to this issue in specific but you may get other errors - that the third line needs to be under `[admin]` so the final config should be like this:

```
# Merging with configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
reporting-disabled = false
[admin]
bind-address = ":8088"
```

It would be better if you got the original config file and then start modifying it in order to follow the same standards without getting new issues related to the file format.